# How to add a change listener to multiple components without executing addChangeListener for each?

Tags: java, swing, listener

Lets say you have a very busy dialogbox and need to know if any of the items where changed except for the Password field. For this example, if the Password field changes, it doesn't matter, but if any of the other fields, radio buttons, checkboxes...... change I need to know when the Button is pressed.

Granted one could add a change listener to every single component (except Password), but as this dialogbox grows, I shouldn't have to worry about remembering to add the change listener to new objects.

Is it possible to add a change listener at some layer then when any component changes it fire. 
Within this routine I can add an IF to check if the component is Password then ignore but if anything else then flag the entire dialog as changed.

[image]

Comment: You have to add listener to every component, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add listener to every component. The good news is that you can iterate over parent's children and add listener in a loop

`parent.getComponents().forEach(c->addChangeListener(yourListener));`

Comment: I think for JTextField, it should be a addDocumentListener if you want to detect a change in them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(AWTEventListener)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener(java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,long)